# Boost::asio async_write_some vs async_send

Tags: c++, boost-asio, send

I noticed only just now that `async_write_some` and `async_send` (second overload) functions in `boost::asio` are completely the same:

`async_write_some` defenition:

```
...
template <typename ConstBufferSequence, typename WriteHandler>
  BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(WriteHandler,
      void (boost::system::error_code, std::size_t))
  async_write_some(const ConstBufferSequence& buffers,
      BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(WriteHandler) handler)
  {
    // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
    // not meet the documented type requirements for a WriteHandler.
    BOOST_ASIO_WRITE_HANDLER_CHECK(WriteHandler, handler) type_check;

    return this->get_service().async_send(this->get_implementation(),
        buffers, 0, BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(WriteHandler)(handler));
  }
...
```

`async_send` definition:

```
...
template <typename ConstBufferSequence, typename WriteHandler>
  BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(WriteHandler,
      void (boost::system::error_code, std::size_t))
  async_send(const ConstBufferSequence& buffers,
      BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_ARG(WriteHandler) handler)
  {
    // If you get an error on the following line it means that your handler does
    // not meet the documented type requirements for a WriteHandler.
    BOOST_ASIO_WRITE_HANDLER_CHECK(WriteHandler, handler) type_check;

    return this->get_service().async_send(
        this->get_implementation(), buffers, 0,
        BOOST_ASIO_MOVE_CAST(WriteHandler)(handler));
  }
...
```

Why there is two identical functions in `boost::asio` library? Are there any historical reasons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They provide two different abstractions:

- `stream.async_write_some()` allows one to generically write to asynchronous stream I/O objects.  For example, this abstraction allows for the higher-level [`async_write()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) composed operation to generically write to [`ip::tcp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html), [`ssl:stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream.html), [`serial_port`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/serial_port.html), etc.  The `async_write_some()` member function is part of the [AsyncWriteStream](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/AsyncWriteStream.html) type requirement.
- `socket.async_send()` allows one to generically write to sockets without regard to the protocol.  For example, this abstraction allows for one to generically write to `ip::tcp::socket`, [`ip::udp::socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html), `local::*_protocol::socket`, and `generic::*_protocol::socket`.  The presence of `socket.async_send()` models closely to the established BSD socket API.